# How to run Xcode 6 on macOS High Sierra(10.13)?

Tags: macos, xcode, high-sierra

I downloaded Xcode from Apple Developer website. When I'm trying to open the app, it shows this error.

> You can’t use this version of the application “Xcode” with this version of macOS.

Can we bypass this check?

Comment: Why would you want to use (the old) version 6 and not Xcode 8 or 9 beta?

Comment: I have a similar requirement, I want to test my app on iOS 7. How can it be done>